# Validate-trigger is not firing in vb6.0

Tags: validation, vb6

In my VB 6.0 project, I have a form in which the user enters a number and hits 'enter', and the validation trigger fires without issue. I moved this logic and column to the login form, and it no longer works. The validation will fire if I manually click on another column, however, clicking 'enter' no longer fires the validation.

Is there some sort of form setting set-up that I am overlooking? Why the #&@! will this simple logic work in one place and not another??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me, the validation that was working when the user clicked enter included this code:

```
Private Sub Text1_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
   KeyAscii = Asc(UCase(Chr(KeyAscii)))
   If KeyAscii = 13 Then 'enter key
      SendKeys "{tab}"
   End If
End Sub
```

I solved my own problem, but figured I would post it in case someone else wanted validation to fire when the user clicks 'enter'.

Comment: The Enter key is meant to activate the Default control on a Form, i.e. a sort of "submit" operation.  Deviation from Windows UI conventions like this is a huge mistake.

Comment: @Bob77 I agree with you 100%, but I have fought this battle and lost with more than 1 supervisor.